# Blender runs very slow on my laptop and freezes a lot

Tags: performance

Blender runs very slow on my laptop and freezes a lot. I did everything to fix it but it didnt work, so I'm thinking the problem might be my computer.

Here's the properties of my laptop:

- Operating System: Windows 10pro (10.0.18362)
- RAM: 8GB
- Processor: intel(R) core i7-8550U CPU 1.80GHZ
- Processor speed: 1992Mhz
- Processor graphic in use: intel UHD graphics 620
- OpenGl version: 4.6
  driver version: 26.20.1007263
  my blender version is 2.82

What should I do?

Comment: Usually this could be due to a graphic card driver issue. Maybe try to update them or in any case use the last recommended version. Also update your post and add the driver version, so others may confirm if they have the same or not. Also, add the blender version, and maybe try with other versions (you can use zipped ones in folders directly after extracting) or reinstall blender.

Comment: There have been some reports with the Intel integrated GPUs on the bug tracker recently (see [T72098](https://developer.blender.org/T72098)). Some have reported that activating the compatibility mode resolved their problems, which may be a workaround until a proper patch is implemented.

Comment: you mean i should download a previos version of blender such as 2.81?